# Angular 8 mat-radio-button checked dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular8

I checked my value using the attribute `[checked]` of `mat-radio-button`.

```
<div class="mb-3" *ngIf="!multiple" class="ttb-filter-list">
    <mat-radio-group class="d-flex flex-column" aria-labelledby="group-radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue">
        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option" color="primary" [checked]="option.checked">
            {{ option.name }}
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

And as you can see the radio button with the id `mat-radio-2` as `ng-reflect-checked="true"`

[image: code]

Is is not checked though.

[image]

Comment: Could you please create a stackBlitz for it?!

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz link.

Comment: Can you show  `filteredOptions` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to set the value in `checked`, it should be set through `ngModel`

Eg:

.ts

```
  filteredOptions = [
    { id: 1, name: "abc" },
    { id: 2, name: "xyz" }
  ];

  radioValue = 2
```

.html

```
<mat-radio-group class="d-flex flex-column" aria-labelledby="group-radio" [(ngModel)]="radioValue">
  <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option.id" color="primary">
    {{ option.name }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-binding-fpfzde?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: yep that is what I was trying to say :) I should have added a code sample

Comment: Nice, effectively my ngmodel was a string when my value was an object. I'll try to change that

Comment: Yes, the value should be what you are setting in ngModel

Comment: Can't we pass an object like `{ id: 1, name: "abc" } ` ? Must I pass only a single value ?

Comment: It should be a primitive type like number, string, boolean

Comment: Thanks for you answers :) Just to let people know,  I managed to have a full object as ngModel and value

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: the answer from @adrita-sharma is showing how to do it correct

My first idea is that your property radioValue is not set properly to what should be checked.

If not please provide a stackblitz to reproduce

Comment: The problem is with the radioValue if I delete the [(ngModel)] it works, but why ? Can't we use [(ngModel)] with a pre-checked value ?

Comment: the radioValue must be set with one value of your list to be able to pre-check it

Comment: Look at the answer from @adrita-sharma that is what I mean